# Why does the sender not receive a bulk emailing they originate?

Tags: civimail, email

To test out CiviMail, I sent a message to the "administrators" mailing group, which has three members, including me. Only two emails were sent out, however. Even though I'm in the group,
the mailing report only reports the two mailings to the other administrators and I did not received the message.

I do not have the "do not email" or any similar box checked in my profile.

Shouldn't bulk mailings go out to all group members, including the mailing originator?

Follow up:

This may be related: Here's an experiment.

I select my own contact and start a CiviMail mailing just to me:

[image]

(For privacy, I've omitted information here, but the email address is correct.)
[image]

I select "Email - schedule/send via CiviMail" from the pulldown.

[image]

But as you can see, CiviMail creates a "hidden smart group" that contains "No Recipients". There's nothing in my contact DB entry to prevent receipt of email.

What am I missing?

Comment: yes it should. was email for 'me' On Hold. Did it go to spam. Can you check your mail.log folder?

Comment: Thanks for the response.

The "On Hold" setting on my profile is off, the "test Email" to me worked.

There's nothing in my Spam (or Junk) folders, but if an email had been sent to me, wouldn't the CiviMail "sent" count be three, not two?

I'm not sure where my "mail.log" folder is. "/var/log/mail.log"? Do I need to ssh somewhere to access it? I've looked at all the reports under "Mailings -> Mailing Reports" and I only see the other two recipients mentioned.

Comment: " if an email had been sent to me, wouldn't the CiviMail "sent" count be three, not two" sorry had skipped that bit. can you paste a screenshot of your mailing report. are you saying it lists 3 target recipients but only 2 successfully sent?

Comment: Does your contact have one primary address and one for bulk mailing? With some recent versions of CiviCRM I found that there were delivery issues with contacts that had two delivery addresses defined.

Comment: rereading this the only thing that i can think of which your screenshots do not dis/prove is that your Contact is not either On Hold, or set to Do Not Mail. In a comment you say "On Hold is off". So that only leaves Do Not Mail as a possible loose end. (Or Francesc's comment re different email in use for Bulk Mail)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found the cause, but I've found a fix that *seems* to work.

If I call up `Edit` on a contact and then `Save` it, even without making any changes, I am able to send that contact bulk email. I cannot be sure, but I suspect that the defective contact records were ones that were imported via CSV from another platform with an older CiviCRM release.

Yes, this seems mysterious and it doesn't exactly increase my confidence in CiviCRM. On the other hand, I'm a release or two behind on WordPress and CiviCRM, so maybe it's already been fixed.

So all I have to do now is `Edit`/`Save` all 1024 (coincidentally, I think, 2**10) contacts in my database. Perhaps I'll make this a group project for my organization! B-)

Comment: possibly the import did not set 'is_primary' on those emails?

Answer (score 0):

My guess with this would be that your email is being caught by your spam rules. We normally see this issue with clients using a email gateway such as sparkpost and the email fails to be delivered to their own domain as the spam filter, or firewall, will stop emails with their domain which are not originating from their expected email gateway. My first point of call would be your networks admin to determine if this is the case, they should see the emails in the spam filters if it is and they would need to whitelist your email sending gateway (SMTP service) that CiviCRM is using.

Comment: Thanks, but I checked my spam folder and it was not there. In any case, as I said above, CiviMail did not report that it was sent, which it should have even if my spam rules caught it.